# SQL EXISTS operator with GROUP BY

Tags: sql

I am currently looking through the EXISTS operator examples on http://www.w3resource.com/sql/special-operators/sql_exists.php# and have come across an example which doesn't quite make sense. The code is as follows:

```
SELECT cust_code,cust_name,cust_city,grade  
FROM customer  
WHERE grade=2 AND  
    EXISTS(  
        SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM customer  
        WHERE grade=2  
        GROUP BY grade  
        HAVING COUNT(*)>2
    );
```

From my understanding, the subquery will always evaluate to TRUE and it doesn't relate to the customer table higher up - so it seems irrelevant to put it in there.

Can anybody explain what the code is trying to achieve here please?

Many Thanks!

Comment: subquery will not return any results if you have <= 2 customers with grade = 2, so not quite always TRUE right?

Comment: It should be explained in w3resource website.

Comment: `... doesn't relate to the customer table higher up` You are correct. Although it is correct, the example is terrible, IMO.

Comment: Trying to achieve? Who knows... Usually `EXISTS` is using a correlated sub-query, but not here.

Comment: `EXISTS Operator

The EXISTS checks the existence of a result of a Subquery. The EXISTS subquery tests whether a subquery fetches at least one row. When no data is returned then this operator returns 'FALSE'.

- See more at: http://www.w3resource.com/sql/special-operators/sql_exists.php#sthash.ZYVpVsr6.dpuf`

Answer (score 2):

`EXISTS` will evaluate to `false` when count of records with `grade=2` is less than or equal to 2. Query checks if there are more than two records with `grade=2`. If there are then show columns mentioned in the outer `select`.

Comment: Correct, the query shows all customers with grade=2 in case there are at least three such customers and none otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

This code validates that there are **at least** two records on `customer` table with `grade  = 2` , if not , the record will be filtered.

Answer (score 0):

The second sub query works by first getting all the rows in the customer table where the grade is equal to 2.

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM customer  
WHERE grade=2
```

The next section of the query below. Groups all these rows together by grade.

```
GROUP BY grade
```

Finally the having count code below excludes any of the groups that don' have at least 2 items in it.

```
HAVING COUNT(*)>2
```

Thus you could have a situation where a number of people have grades and this is input into the customer table. If two or more people don't have the same grade this query will find no results.

Answer (score 0):

> grade=2 AND
>       EXISTS(
>           SELECT COUNT(*)
>           FROM customer
>
>           WHERE grade=2
>
>           GROUP BY grade
>
>           HAVING COUNT(*)>2
>       );

```
TRUE and TRUE =TRUE
```

So your query checks if Grade=2 and there is atleast one row with below condition

```
WHERE grade=2  
        GROUP BY grade  
        HAVING COUNT(*)>2
```

If both conditions doesn't satify,your query won't return any result set